# What is the correct way to set a bool vec uniform in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my shader I have a `bvec4` uniform defined like so:

```c
uniform bvec4 Flags;
```

What is the correct way to set this from my code?

I initially assumed I would set it with `glUniform1i(location, bits)`, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [OpenGL specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) section 2.2.1:

> When the type of internal state is boolean, zero integer or floating-point values are converted to FALSE and non-zero values are converted to TRUE

So you can use `glUniform4iv` and pass it a buffer of 4 integers where `bits[I]` occupies `ints[I]`. The values will be converted to `false` if zero, and `true` otherwise.

Similarly, you can use `glUniform3iv` to set a `bvec3`, `glUniform2iv` to set a `bvec2`, and `glUniform1iv` or `glUniform1i` to set a `bool`.

Here is an example in Java using LWJGL 3:

```
GL20.glUniform4iv(location, new int[]{bits & 0b1, bits & 0b10, bits & 0b100, bits & 0b1000});
```

You should probably create an `int[]` or an `IntBuffer` once and reuse it though.